# Cryptic clue for business people?

Tags: cryptic-clues, puzzle-creation, difficulty-rating

I have been asked to produce something funny or interesting in a video for work (yay working from home, right?)... so I decided to produce a "Puzzle Hunt".  As part of it I was hoping for some feedback on the step that I am pretty sure is the hardest.  The following cryptic clue was created by me:

**RUN COMPANY EXECUTIVES GRAPHICAL INFORMATION SUMMARIES (10)**

Two questions:

- Does it make sense for seasoned puzzle solvers? (presumably you)
- Is it too difficult for "normal people"? (tongue firmly in cheek)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a valid cryptic clue. I don't think it's too difficult for normal people. It took me maybe half a minute, but variance here is really large; it depends on what you happen to think of in what order. (Also, I wasn't timing. It certainly wasn't as little as 15 seconds or as long as 2 minutes, but beyond that I wouldn't trust my judgement much.)

One thing I don't like very much (but it's a minor blemish if it's a blemish at all) is

> cluing BOARDS by "company executives", for two nitpicky reasons. The first is that most of the people on a typical board *aren't* company executives. The second is that "boards" = "executives" feels like a bit of a type error: the things that make up "boards" are the boards, not the people on them. (*A* board is made up of people.)

For the second of those reasons, I think the clue would be slightly improved by making it

> Run company executives graphical information summary (9)

although that doesn't address my other quibble.

The surface reading is pretty good. The only thing I don't like about it is that it seems like it wants to be "executives'" rather than just "executives", but adding that apostrophe would be misleading in a way I'm not sure is quite fair. (Generally punctuation can be ignored, but apostrophes feel to me like they aren't just punctuation.) Ah, how about this?

> Graphical information summary run by company executives (9)

Comment: Sorry, but even with the answer I have no idea how the puzzle works.

Comment: Would it be improved with "directors"?  Would that remove the first problem?  I agree with the apostrophe, I wasn't sure if I should include it or not!  I like your reorder but I sort of need the result to be plural if possible!

Comment: "Directors" is certainly a bit more accurate but I worry that maybe it makes the clue too easy. The reordering doesn't really make any difference to singular versus plural; make it "summaries" and change the enumeration to (10) and it's still fine. Perhaps consider "companies' directors" instead of "company directors" to address my other quibble?